# Where does Facebook store multi millions of Images and Videos. In database or somewhere else? if so, Where?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I am completely new to database. I require some information regarding where does the Facebook which stores millions and millions of pictures and videos. Do they store it in their database and then the images/videos gets retrieved through the query? I have read few times from some people that you should not store the images/videos in the database but they never mentioned why and where else should you store them if not in the database. Please provide me as much information as possibly you can. It'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Build another Facebook?  Learn about databases in general? Come up to speed as aprogrammer who can handle databases?  You may have a long learning curve ahead of you, depending on how far you want to go.

Comment: Hi Walter, i am a student. I am trying to learn about database in details since I have a project to create which I was thinking to do it on mini social networking website.

Comment: Then you do not have any performance problems at all. The way Facebook does it is only because THEY have performance issues that need to be solved. Whenever you are big enough, you need a specialized solution for exactly the problem you are facing. But you cannot know what kind of problem this will be unless you are getting close to having it. Forget about optimizing whatever you want to build! Start building a working system first. Make it work. And then start observing if there is anything to improve. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil!"

Comment: It's always better to store images in local drive and store the image paths to database. It is a good practice to dynamically generate unique file name before storing in to the database and locally.
Imagine of a situation where you have thousands of images to store (e.g. school ERP system). You will end up spending GBs of spaces in database whereas your work would have been completed within few MBs by storing the images paths.

Comment: @PankajKumarThapa I know this is old, but to add to your point, most websites will simply store the image under the universal time for the “filename”. Since a specific point in time can only occur once, each image will have a unique name. And as you mentioned, then the file will be stored on some sort of local drive. At Yahoo when I worked there, believe it or not, we just used a file system to store the files. No databases. That was many years ago though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically? As files. On a disk. Then store the *paths* to those files in a database for easy lookup. (Or store a key that can be used by some network service to find the file and stream it.)

Comment: how would they ensure that every server have access to all pictures?

Comment: @bubakazouba network attached storage, or networked daemons running on the servers containing disks.

Comment: Thank you, Can you recommend me a book or a name of a topic to read about it and effectively become an "expert" in that field? (i.e I would like to setup a bunch of servers with that capability)

Comment: So no byte arrays or anything of that nature?

Answer (score 8):

Facebook uses a specialized and optimized solution that exactly fits the task of storing millions of images. This solution will not be useful for a general case, especially for someone who is just starting to learn about databases.

Also remember that a database does not necessarily mean that it uses SQL. The file system also is a database for storing files. It is also optimized for only this task, which means that trying to store something different than files and trying to get it back will either be impossible or inefficient.

SQL databases have the feature to store all kind of data, and offering the programmer to decide which data to return at a later point in time. This makes them more inefficient when there is no need to later decide which data to return, but more adaptable to changing requirements. The Facebook image storage can only be used for storing images.

Comment: Why do you call general-purpose databases, "SQL databases"? It implies that all general-purpose database engines are based on SQL, which isn't true. Do not forget that there are non-SQL databases too, such as Neo4j.

Comment: I don't. I call a database "SQL database" only exactly when it uses SQL as the query language, and I even explicitly give the file system as an example for an alternative storage that isn't SQL. You misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Then what brings SQL databases here? I don't see why you had to talk specifically about "Filesystem Database vs SQL Database" instead of "FileSystem Database vs Typical Database."

Comment: My question would be: Why do you call "neo4j" a general purpose database. It isn't, it is intended for graph data storage and retrieval. In fact, my answer tries to get away from the "general purpose database" thinking and introduce the idea that each database or storage system has their use case and drawback and should be chosen carefully. And to illustrate that "database" isn't very descriptive, the typical example most people are familiar with is "SQL vs. file system". It's probably not useful to go into the details of how Facebook stores stuff when the OP is new completely new to database.

Comment: I never said or implied that neo4j is a general-purpose DB engine. I just used it as an example of a non-SQL DB engine, which it is. I should have specified a non-SQL general-purpose DB as an example though, such as MongoDB, to avoid confusions though, my bad.

I totally get your point, but my humble opinion is that classifying a DB engine based on its API (whether it's SQL or noSQL DB), rather than its storage characteristics is kind of misleading in this specific case (as least that's what it seemed to me). How the DB engine works here is the issue here, not its API.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook is not storing their images and videos in the database. Each file is uploaded directly into a server dedicated just for that and they are located around the world, an example could be Pineville, Oregon or the newly establishes servers in Sweden. However, as said, they have them everywhere.

What is stored in the database is simply the paths of those different files. 
Based on your location those paths you are looking for will change, and therefor you can access different servers from all over the world depending on where you are.

Answer (score 3):

You don't store images or files in a database, you only store data (numbers, text, etc). The files themselves are simply stored in a content distribution network that can serve up the images to browsers based on closest location. The NAMES of those images might be stored in a database somewhere. It's impossible to say in what manner they are stored though.

Answer (score -2):

very Baciacally telling , FB uses **akamai cdn** ,Another service provider. you can read more about them from [akamai.com](https://akamai.com)  this is same as **Amazon CloudFront** [Amazon cloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html).this being said , people can learn more by using the reference. Tháńkź..